# Oracle query to identify columns having special characters

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to write a SQL query to return rows which has anything other than 
`alphabets`, `numbers`, `spaces` and `following chars '.', '{','[','}',']'`
Column has alphabets like `Ÿ`, `¿`

eg:- There's a table `TEST` with 2 columns - `EmpNo` and `SampleText`
`EmpNo` is simple sequence and `SampleText` has values like

```
('12345abcde','abcdefghij','1234567890','ab c d 1 3','abcd$%1234','%^*&^%$#$%','% % $ #  %','abcd 12}34{','MINNEAŸPOLIS','THAN ¿VV ¿A')
```

I want to write a query which should eliminate all rows which have even a single special character except `.{[}]`. In above example, it should return `EmpNo - 1,2,3,4 and 8`
I tried `REGEXP_LIKE` but I'm not getting exactly what I need.

Query I used:

```
SELECT * FROM test 
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(sampleText, '[^A-Z^a-z^0-9^[^.^{^}]' ,'x');
```

This is not ignoring blanks and I also need to ignore closing bracket ']'

Answer (score 4):

You can use regular expressions for this, so I think this is what you want:

```
select t.*
from test t
where not regexp_like(sampletext, '.*[^a-zA-Z0-9 .{}\[\]].*')
```

Comment: It's not working. However, thsi served the purpose to a major extent.
SELECT * FROM test WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(sampleText, '[^A-Z^a-z^0-9^[^.^{^}^ ]' )
Not able to exclude ] though

Comment: Sometimes, you might need to use two backslashes to escape a characters, depending on how you connect to the database.

Answer (score 2):

Compare the length using lengthB and length function in oracle.

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE length(sampletext) <> lengthb(sampletext)
```

Comment: I don't think this accomplishes the asker's goal, unfortunately.  For this problem, even characters like `$` count as special characters, but `LENGTH('foobar$')` and `LENGTHB('foobar$')` both return `7`.

Comment: Thinking on the title of the question "Oracle query to identify columns having special characters", I think that this answer is just the best. That's what I need. Thanks Raj Ratan.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the answer to above problem.
Below query will return rows which have even a signle occurrence of characters besides
alphabets, numbers, square brackets, curly brackets,s pace and dot.
Please note that position of closing bracket ']' in matching pattern is important.

Right ']' has the special meaning of ending a character set definition.  It wouldn't make any sense to end the set before you specified any members, so the way to indicate a literal right ']' inside square brackets is to put it immediately after the left '[' that starts the set definition

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(sampletext,  '[^]^A-Z^a-z^0-9^[^.^{^}^ ]' );
```

Answer (score 1):

They key is the backslash escape character will not work with the right square bracket inside of the character class square brackets (it is interpreted as a literal backslash inside the character class square brackets).  Add the right square bracket with an OR at the end like this:

```
select EmpNo, SampleText
from test 
where NOT regexp_like(SampleText, '[ A-Za-z0-9.{}[]|]');
```